# Visual Studio 2019 - C++ link Boost libraries statically

Tags: visual-c++, boost

I'm building a C++ console app in VS 2019 that uses some boost::filesystem functionality. The program runs fine on my development machine, but when I run it on the actual target machine I get:

```
The program can't start because boost_filesystem-vc142-mt-gd-x64-1_78.dll is missing from your computer.
```

I'm trying to link the boost libs in statically, but apparently I'm not hitting the correct options. What's the correct settings to get an independent EXE? I should mention, I have boost-filesystem:x64-windows                      1.78.0 and boost-filesystem:x64-windows-static 1.78.0 installed via vcpkg.

Compiler cmd line:

```
/JMC /permissive- /ifcOutput "x64\Debug\" /GS /W3 /Zc:wchar_t /ZI /Gm- /Od /sdl /Fd"x64\Debug\vc142.pdb" /Zc:inline /fp:precise /D "_DEBUG" /D "_CONSOLE" /D "_UNICODE" /D "UNICODE" /errorReport:prompt /WX- /Zc:forScope /RTC1 /Gd /MTd /FC /Fa"x64\Debug\" /EHsc /nologo /Fo"x64\Debug\" /Fp"x64\Debug\BoosLink.pch" /diagnostics:column
```

Linker cmd line:

```
/OUT:"E:\DevProjects\BoostLink\BoosLink\x64\Debug\BoosLink.exe" /MANIFEST /NXCOMPAT /PDB:"E:\DevProjects\BoostLink\BoosLink\x64\Debug\BoosLink.pdb" /DYNAMICBASE "kernel32.lib" "user32.lib" "gdi32.lib" "winspool.lib" "comdlg32.lib" "advapi32.lib" "shell32.lib" "ole32.lib" "oleaut32.lib" "uuid.lib" "odbc32.lib" "odbccp32.lib" /DEBUG /MACHINE:X64 /INCREMENTAL /PGD:"E:\DevProjects\BoostLink\BoosLink\x64\Debug\BoosLink.pgd" /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /ManifestFile:"x64\Debug\BoosLink.exe.intermediate.manifest" /LTCGOUT:"x64\Debug\BoosLink.iobj" /ERRORREPORT:PROMPT /ILK:"x64\Debug\BoosLink.ilk" /NOLOGO /TLBID:1
```

Comment: Did you compile boost as static libraries?

Comment: I installed the static and dynamic versions of boost with vcpkg